# Why Lord Vishnu incarnates only in Bharata Varsha (India)?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, india

One question raised in my mind, why lord Vishnu incarnates only in Bhartha Varsha (India)? It is little bit confusing for me, because I can't find any valid resources. Please provide some evidence through the scriptures.

Comment: Where it is said that Lord Vishnu born in India?

Comment: @Mr_Green By Vishnu he means Avatar of Vishnu.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: you got the point brother..!!

Comment: @TheDestroyer I don't think there was any place with name India at that time.

Comment: @Mr_Green :yeah, but it's called Bharatbumi , or I can say as geographically, Lord take birth the particular part of India , I know that at that time , there was no place/term like India, but now day' that place called India, so that's why I mention India.

Comment: @Mr_Green By india he means Bharatha Khanda (Indian Subcontinent). But i think OP is not correct fully, as Kurma avatar happened in Cosmic ocean and Varaha happened for entire earth.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: yeah, but as you know that, the human avatar, like Rama,parsurama, krishna,balarama, and in kali-yuga Lord visnu will take Kali-avatar which is mention in our scriptures.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: So, I am talking about that avatar , Is there any reason because, I feel like that there should be reason to take birth on particular place and time. it's matter. may be some where in scriptures it has mention.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna you are asking about Kalki avatar?

Comment: @Mr_Green: No, mate, It's my spellng mistake take those instead of that in my previous comment, I am talking about all(human) avatar, i just mention to clear the doubt of user(the Destroyer), So, that's why mention the kalki-avatar, but here my question the previous avatar as well as the next avatar,Lord vishnu choose the india, not any other country/continent.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna oh ok sorry. I didn't get that.

Comment: @Mr_Green: No problem, brother. :)

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I have heard many meditators mention that they feel a jolt of spiritual energy when they enter India, when entering from another country. Maybe, thats why.

Comment: @AmitSaxena: yes, maybe, but as you know that, like lord vishnu took birth as lord krishna on 12'o clock midnight, so he decided time as per Graha & Naksatra etc etc, so may be some interesting reason behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If we just talk about known oldest Civilization, Indus
   civilization(mohenjo daro or harappa civilization) comes into our
   mind.
2. If you List the Oldest civilizations, you will not find more that 10-12, That means that other world was not developed/grown enough or
   people didn't live there at that time.
3. Referencing from the above point we can conclude, As Indian scripture says, We are living in KALYUGA which is 5000 year old, That time no other place was developed enough.

This way you might link the logic (connect the dots)..

Source :

1. [Kalyuga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Yuga)
2. [Oldest Civilizations](http://www.ancienthistorylists.com/ancient-civilizations/10-oldest-ancient-civilizations-ever-existed/)

Comment: @DesigningLives It's interesting , but as we talk about oldest Civilization, it maybe possible at that time other placed was not develped enough, but if we conclued Oldest Civilization Harrappa which was  now in pakistan, I know at that time The whole bhartvarsa include pakistan , afganistan , nepal ,tibat and bangladesh and many other countries, but if you figure out the birth place of Lord Vishnu which is mostly occured now present state of UP around UP, like Vrindavan ,Ayoudhaya , and also kalki avatar which will occur in Shambal Village which is also in UP.

Comment: @DesigningLives: So, it's sound intresting, like maybe your logic is some how right, but still I have some confusion.

Comment: @DesigningLives: and yes brother, put some valid resources, because You just attached WIKI-pedia link, and as you know these links are not authenticate because anybody can edit it, so, try to attach valid evidence from scriptures....