# Why god takes birth only in India?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, gods, avatars

Why God take birth only in India (Aryavrata) ? Why not in any other place ?

Comment: [Related1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/why-all-avatars-and-granthas-references-happened-only-in-india-and-not-elsewhe)  [Related2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57599/why-do-all-gods-in-hindusim-who-took-incarnation-on-earth-are-localised-to-india)   [Related3](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35954/did-lord-vishnu-have-any-avatar-in-other-parts-of-world-as-well)   [Related4](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45215/why-are-all-the-avatars-of-vishnu-born-in-north-india)

Comment: [Related5](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12454/why-lord-vishnu-incarnates-only-in-bharata-varsha-india) [Related6](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14833/do-our-scriptures-declare-that-if-god-has-to-descend-on-earth-then-that-place-ha)

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be assumed that Ishwara takes birth only in India.

**Bhagavad Gita**

> śrī bhagavānuvāca

> bahūni mē vyatītāni janmāni tava cārjuna.
> tānyahaṅ vēda sarvāṇi na tvaṅ vēttha parantapa৷৷4.5৷৷

> The Blessed Lord said - O Arjuna, **many lives of Mine have passed, and so have yours. I know them all, (but) you know not,** O scorcher of enemies!

If even Arjuna does not know the many births of Ishwara, (as well as his own many births), it can be reasonably assumed that **we dont know the many births of Ishwara either.** We know only some incarnations of Ishwara.

It is not necessary for scriptures to mention all the births of Ishwara (if they had mentioned, Arjuna, a learned man, would have likely known). Further, as creation has no beginning, Ishwara would have taken birth innumerable times. There is no reason to assume that all these births took place only in India.